# eclipse plugin project plugin dependency hell

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this code:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor t;

IWorkspaceRoot root= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

final IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

System.out.println("root" + root.getLocation().toOSString());

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            IPath projectDotProjectFile = new Path("C:\\Users\\rezbi\\eclipse-workspace\\AutoRefactor-master\\AutoRefactor-master" + "/.project");
            IProjectDescription projectDescription = workspace.loadProjectDescription(projectDotProjectFile);
            IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(projectDescription.getName());
            JavaCapabilityConfigurationPage.createProject(project, projectDescription.getLocationURI(), null);
            //project.create(null);
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

// and now get the workbench to do the work
final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
workbench.getDisplay().syncExec(runnable);


IProject[] projects = root.getProjects();

for(IProject project: projects){
    System.out.println(project.getName());
}
```

I followed the instructions as mentioned in the link below:
http://techdc.blogspot.com/2015/01/eclipse-workbench-has-not-been-created.html

I added the following dependencies only:

```
org.apache.felix.gogo.command
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
org.eclipse.equinox.console
org.eclipse.osgi
```

Unfortunately it is giving plugin dependency hello - I run the app, I get unresolved dependencies, I add the dependencies and there are more unresolved dependencies. And if I select "add required bundles" from run configuration, then I get "Workbench has not been created yet. Error while creating OSGi modules"

So is there an easier way to get around this?

Update:
How I am creating the project is here:
http://codeandme.blogspot.com/2012/02/creating-headless-application.html

So this is a plugin project.

And to run I right click on the manifest file. Select run as and then osgi framework. Note: I also tried including the plugin dependencies from run configuration. Then I tried to run > Eclipse Application. Either way I get the same result : workbench not created yet.

In the same java class the following code works:

```
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String PACKAGE_NAME = "cucumber";
        //final IPackageFragment packageFragment = JavaCoreHelper.getPackageFragment(PACKAGE_NAME);
        //System.out.println(packageFragment);
        //final ICompilationUnit cu = packageFragment.createCompilationUnit("Application5.java", "", true, null);
        //IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        //IProject m_project = root.getProject("cucumber");
        //System.out.println("m_project "+m_project);
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

        System.out.println("HELLO ");

        IProject[] projects = root.getProjects();

        for (IProject project : projects) {
            try {
                printProjectInfo(project);
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // createAProject();



        //System.out.println("test "+root.getProject(name));
        return null;
    }
```

But as soon as I try accessing workbench things break.

Comment: Do you know about Maven? It's great for managing dependencies in Java.

Comment: Yes but eclipse did nt use maven to build ... maven is a useless answer here. (At least say tycho)

Comment: Can you provide your full manifest?

Comment: Do you run an eclipse product or you just want to create an application base on eclipse ?

Comment: 'Workbench has not been created yet' suggests you are not running this as an Eclipse plugin - a plain Java program cannot access the workbench. Tell us exactly how you are running this.

Comment: The blog you reference is rather unclear but it is **not** about how to run code which actually wants to use the workbench- it is about running OSGi code which doesn't use the workbench.